# "Настоенный" или "настоянный"?

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно: `"НастоЯнный на коре дуба"` или `"НастоЕнный на коре дуба"`?

Comment: Как правильно: "заяц" (напр., Lepus europaeus) или "заец" (напр., Lepus europaeus)?

Answer (score 2):

В Большом толковом словаре (www.gramota.ru) есть два омонимичных глагола *настоять*.

Нас интересует глагол с таким значением:

1. НАСТОЯТЬ, -стою, -стоишь; настой; **настоЯнный**; -стоян, -а, -о; св.
2. что (на чём).
    Приготовить настой
    чего-л. Н. ромашку, зверобой, липовый цвет.
3. что (на чём).
    Придать спиртному напитку особый вкус, аромат, поместив в него какое-л. растительное вещество. Н. спирт на калгане. Н. наливку из вишни. Н. водку на лимонных корочках. < Настаивать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Настаиваться, -ается; страд.

В орфографическом словаре Лопатина тоже есть слово **настоЯнный**; краткая форма: настоян, настояна.

Comment: Да, согласен, поторопился, задумался о другом.

Answer (score 1):

Если инфинитив оканчивается на -ать (ять), то перед НН в причастии пишется А(Я). В остальных случаях - Е. Настоять - настоянный. Сравни: вывалЯть (в снегу) - вывалЯнный, вывалИть (из шкафа) - вывалЕнный.

Answer (score 1):

а вот словарь Ушакова приводит вариант настоЕнный...
НАСТОЕННЫЙ, настоенная, настоенное; настоен, настоена, настоено. прич. страд. прош. вр. от [настоять](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/876874)

Answer (score 1):

Словарь Ушакова относится к 1935 году, то есть до принятия Правил 1956 года, когда орфография ряда слов была исправлена.   Однако интересен тот факт, что вариант  «настоенный»  применялся и после 1956 года, а также применяется и сейчас, хотя во всех  современных словарях указывается «настоянный», например: «Но лучше всего пить валериановый чай, настоенный на корнях» (Е. Рерих, 1931-1935). «Из-под крышки вырывается аромат, настоенный на крепком бульоне» (Е. Светлова, 2003).

Также отметим, что для всех глаголы с корнем РОВН суффикс Я меняется на ЕНН: выровненный, приравненный, уравненный:  «Порог, и выровненный, чуть обузданный, никому с собою баловаться не позволит (В. Астафьев, 1974).

Получается, что орфография страдательных причастий прошедшего времени, образованных от глаголов с суффиксом Я,  ОПРЕДЕЛИЛАСЬ НЕ СРАЗУ. Дело в том, что  суффикс ЕНН распространен в большей степени, например: получить – полученный (И меняется на ЕНН), увлечь – увлеченный (суффикс ЕНН при отсутствии глагольного суффикса).

Если глагольные суффиксы И/Я  различны по смыслу, то сохранение суффикса важно: пристрелить – пристреленный, пристрелять – пристрелянный, вывалить – вываленный, вывалять – вывалянный. Если такой пары нет,  то замена суффикса Я суффиксом ЕНН тоже считалась возможной: настоять – настоенный, разменять – размененный (сейчас пишется только «разменянный»): «И черная стая кидала меня в фаэтон; и размененный фунт испарялся (А. Белый).

Answer (score 0):

Разные слова. На примере: вываленные на землю дрова, вывалянные в муке клецки. Разные предлоги, теперь переходим к насто*нный.

Настоенное на травах питьё.

Настоянный в паровой бане отвар.

Настоенный на коре дуба, настоянный в дупле дуба).